# How iterate over views in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, view, collections

Is there build-in mechanism in angular to create collection views? I have a collaction of data which are mapped to form like that:

```
<from>
    <input type="checkbox"/> {{value1}} <br/>
    <input type="checkbox"/> {{value2}} <br/>
    <input type="button" value="prev"/>
    <input type="button" value="next"/>
</from>
```

E.g. a collection is fetched, then form is displayed for first value, user click on check boxes and go to next form with next value and etc. Is there build-in mechanism in angular for such situations?

Answer (score 0):

There is a mechanism. You can attach the button to a state change. You can associate a state with a view and corresponding controller, if you want to separate out the controllers.

Here's a great article on it:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/3-simple-tips-for-using-ui-router

Comment: It is good, but how to know id for next veiw? Say that I have an report with subresports. Say that cureent url is `/myReport/:reportId/subreport/:subId` when I click next how to know the next sub repost id? I can grab all subid, order them, and select next from current `subId`, but may be angular has similar functionality out-of-thebox?

Comment: I'm not sure how your system determines the next state, but you could have it returned to your model. So for example, your object might look like:

'{ReportId : 1,SubId: 1,NextSubId: 2}'